# Natural deduction for predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate, coq

I've been stuck on a particular predicate logic problem (using Coq) for a long time. I've solved 30-40 predicate logic problems already but with this one I just can't figure it out.

This is the problem:
~all x, (P(x) / (Q(x) -> T(x))) -> ~all x, T(x).

[Or in box form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VDLF.png)

Can anyone send me in the right direction? Thanks!

Edit:

This is the coq code for the problem:

```
Variables P Q T : D -> Prop.

Theorem pred_015 : ~all x, (P(x) \/ (Q(x) -> T(x))) -> ~all x, T(x).
Proof.
imp_i H.



Qed.
```

Comment: Could you translate you formula into Coq and show us the beginning of your proof script?

Comment: Can you prove it on paper, the old fashioned way?

Comment: Have you tried with "forall" instead of "all"

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like your are using some very old version of Coq.
After adding a missing declaration for `D`, and replacing `all` with `forall`, we get a statement that does not look provable.
However, if I had a set of parentheses, I get a goal that is now provable. See the following code:

```
Variable D : Set.
Variables P Q T : D -> Prop.

Theorem pred_015 : (~forall x, (P(x) \/ (Q(x) -> T(x)))) -> ~forall x, T(x).
Proof.
```

Now, I don't think I should be giving the solution to this here, in public, but it's quite easy if you remember that `~H` is defined as `H -> False`.